# Opening different page without reloading or refreshing using JS

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to link to another page without refreshing or reloading the page using JS. I'm having a hard time figuring it out

I need, I'm new in JS

Here is my Navbar Code

```
<div id="app">
        <nav id="nav">
            <div>
                <a class="nav-a on" onclick="home()" style="pointer-events: none; transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0px);"
                    href="/">HOME</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a class="nav-a" onclick="work()" style="transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0px); pointer-events: all;"
                    href="/work.html">WORK</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img class="logo" src="Other Files/SVG/LogoName(White).svg" alt="LOGO">
            </div>
            <div>
                <a class="nav-a" onclick="about()" style="transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0px); pointer-events: all;"
                    href="/about.html">ABOUT</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a class="nav-a" onclick="contact()" style="transform: translate3d(0%, 0%, 0px); pointer-events: all;"
                    href="/contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to build a Single Page Application (SPA) using native JavaScript (no libraries)?

Comment: You need to use React.Js

Comment: No, you don't need to use React @KannuMandora.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the use of [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

This allows you to load HTML from a URL, and display it in an element in your page.

Mock HTML:

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="/contactus.html">Contact Us </a>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#links > a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //so the browser doesn't follow the link

        $("#content").load(this.href, function() {
            //execute here after load completed
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but im having a problem when i use '.click' it is a strikethrough text. What does it mean?

Comment: '.click' is going to be trigger whenever you click on the link tag, so we can prevent the default behavior of the browser (which is reloading the page) by calling 'e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Ghassan Dabak's jquery example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76646678/opening-different-page-without-reloading-or-refreshing-using-js#76646768) you could also achieve this easily in native javaScript:

```js
let contentDiv = document.querySelector(".content");
let btnsHTML = document.querySelectorAll(".a__html");
btnsHTML.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
    // disable default bevior for link elements
    e.preventDefault();

    // delete previously loaded content
    contentDiv.innerHTML = "";

    // get href from link element
    let href = e.currentTarget.href;

    // fetch external html asynchronously
    let response = await fetch(href);
    
    
    try {
      // add content if URL could be accessd
      if (response.ok) {
        let html = await response.text();
        // parse HTML
        let dom = new DOMParser()
          .parseFromString(html, "text/html")
          .querySelector("body");

        // append all child elements from body
        contentDiv.append(...dom.children);
      } else {
        throw new Error(
          JSON.stringify({
            code: response.status,
            message: response.statusText
          })
        );
      }
     // catch errors for invalid or blocked URLs
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      contentDiv.innerHTML = error;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<p><a class="a__html" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdn/html-examples/main/link-rel-preload/fonts/index.html">Load Fonts example</a></p>
<p><a class="a__html" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdn/html-examples/main/custom-select/index.html">Load Select example</a></p>
<p><a class="a__html" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdn/html-examples/main/custom-select/index2.html">Load non existing source</a></p>


<div class="content">
  
</div>
```

The basic steps are the same:

- **disable default click behavior** of links via [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)
- retrieve external content via [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch). This is a **asynchronous** process. In short: We need to wait until the external content is loaded.

This concept of loading external content and append it to the current DOM without reloading is commonly referred to as [**AJAX**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX).

Be careful applying `pointer-events:none` in CSS:
This will also **disable any pointer events** (click, mouse over etc.) attached by JS event listeners.